# Full outer join in crystal reports is disabled

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

In crystal I am trying to do a full outer join however the option is disabled (greyed out) in the database expert.  Does anyone know why or how to get this to work so I can select it?

Comment: What are you using as a data source?

Comment: Hey sorry for the long delay; I actually solved this problem.